# How to exclude some letter in order by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table with these columns: id, placement
my placement is type text and looks like this: A-L-100, A-L-101, A-R-100, ...
When I do order by placement, It gives all A-L at first then A-R. Is there any option to get A-Ls and A-Rs after each other order by their first letter and their number?

Something like this A-L-100, A-R-100

my current sql:

```
SELECT * FROM inventory ORDER BY placement
```

Comment: As I understand you want to order by placement like.
A-L-100,
A-R-100,
A-L-101 ?

Comment: Does the current data pattern stay the same for the whole data set?

Comment: @kanils_yes I want to have all A's first of all and ordered by their number then all B's and so on

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan not sure but I think so

Comment: but there's no `B`, and the logic is not clear whether there should be hyphen before all numeric values, and all values should end with whole digits

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I guess he has it in DB as B-L-100, something like that

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I have this pattern from A-R-100 and to Z-R-999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to order by the numeric suffix first and then by the letters' prefix. So here it is using regular expressions.

```sql
with inventory(placement) as (values ('A-L-100'), ('A-L-101'), ('A-R-100'))
select * from inventory 
 order by substring(placement from '(\d+)$'), 
          substring(placement from '(^[^\d]+)');
```

After your comment - order by the leading letter and then by the trailing number.

```sql
with inventory(placement) as 
(
 values 
 ('B-L-100'), ('B-L-101'), ('B-R-100'),
 ('A-L-100'), ('A-L-101'), ('A-R-100')
)
select * from inventory 
 order by left(placement, 1), substring(placement from '(\d+)$');
```

Comment: thanks but this gives B 100 after A 100. I want all the A's first and ordered by their number then all B's then ordered by number

Comment: only used `select * from inventory 
 order by left(placement, 1), substring(placement from '(\d+)$');` and it worked

Comment: Sure, the `with` part is real data mock-up.